# R decimal comma instead of decimal point in ggplot scales::percent

Tags: r, number-formatting, decimal-point

I have been trying to get R to print a `,` instead of `.` in the percentage labels of my plot, but it doesn't work with any of the methods I found so far. I suspect that running

`format(data, decimal.mark=",")` or `options(OutDec= ",")` might not work because I am requesting the percentages to be printed from the `label=scales::percent(Prozent/100)`. I have tried using some kind of `paste(Prozent+"%")` as a workaround, but the point remains. :(

```
plot <- ggplot(probleme, aes(x=reorder(Name, Häufigkeit), y= Häufigkeit, fill = mean)) +
          geom_col(position="dodge") +
          coord_flip() + 
          scale_fill_gradient(low = "#FEDFE8",  high = "#AC0634", limits=c(6,8), breaks = c(6,7,8))+
          scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,1650), expand = c(0,0.1))+
          scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) + 
          geom_text(aes(label=scales::percent(Prozent/100)), 
                 position = position_dodge(0.5), hjust = -0.02, colour = "black", size=5)
```

Where in my code can I specify that I want a decimal comma?
Any help would be appreciated :) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `decimal.mark = ","` to your `geom_text()` command to modify the comma symbol.

```
geom_text(aes(label=scales::percent(Prozent/100,decimal.mark = ",")), 
                 position = position_dodge(0.5), hjust = -0.02, colour = "black", size=5)
```